# Should I edit the fragment or activity xml in Eclipse for app development?

Tags: android, eclipse

Hi super new to app development but I'm unsure as to whether I should edit the fragment or activity xml? the app I'm making is not for public use so it doesn't need to be used on multiple screen sizes.

If I delete one it causes an error in my java so I was also wondering if it is necessary to have both?

Thanks!

Comment: i didn't understand any things that you said :(
more details please :D

Comment: You can do it either way.  Depends on if fragments would help with your program or not.  Since we don't know what you're doing, we can't help you.

Answer (score 0):

No you don't need both if you are not going to use the Fragments in your app. you can delete the fragment xml and the fragment class in the main activity.